# How do i preform a Jquery function after drop down list change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm struggling to move into the change function after i have made a change to my drop down list?

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="ICCMJScripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ddRequestCategory").change(function () {
        //Do something
    });
 });
</script>
```

Here is my drop down list.

```
<ICCM:ICCMDropDownList style="width:185px;" runat="server" ID="ddRequestCategory" name="ddRequestCategory" TabIndex="1" AppendDataBoundItems="true" >
   <Items>
     <asp:ListItem Value="" Text="" Selected="True" />    
   </Items>   
</ICCM:ICCMDropDownList>
```

Comment: You no longer need the `language` and `type` attributes in your `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use ClientID as the html gererated by asp.net has different id then you have assigned.

```
$("#<%= ddRequestCategory.ClientID %>").change(function () {
        //Do something
});
```

If you are using .net framework 4 or above then you can use [ClientIDMode="static"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the same id in the generated html by asp.net.

Comment: I got this error? The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Comment: This may help, http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/12/aspnet-controls-collection-cannot-be.html

Comment: Thanks error is gone, but still not able to move into the change function?

Comment: Put the script tags just before end closing body tag as it is best practice and show us the generated jquery code

Comment: Found a work around, but thanks for all the help. +1

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the code behind in the form load.

```
DropDownListName.Attributes.Add("onchange", "jsFunctionName();");
```

When the DropDownList selectedItemIndex is changed then your function is called and you can do what ever you need from there.

Answer (score 0):

Use ON function to trigger the event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selectID').on('change', function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
});
```

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9eDS7/